# Apply mean function for all variables

Tags: r

I have two datasets A and B. I want to perform group and apply mean for  varibles wf,sd in dataset A and all the variables in dataset B

dataset A have variables as,df,er,wf,sd,gh,rt,we,sd,xc,as,df,fg,gh,rhj

dataset B have variables we,sd,xc,as,df,fg,gh,rhj,

```
z<-names(b)
dfdre<-new %>%
group_by( as,df,er) %>%
summarize(numbobs =n(), wf= mean(wf), sd= mean(sd), z= mean(z) z= mean(z))
```

I know there is something wrong in the code. I am trying to apply mean for varaibles wf,sd and all the variables in dataset B.Could you please correct me?

Comment: Did you meant to summarise the columns in 'A' that have the same column names in 'B' along with 'wf', 'sd'.

Comment: I want to summarize columns wf,sd of dataset A and the all the column names in dataset B

Comment: My question is whether you need two summarize output

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise_each`

```
z1 <- setdiff(z, c('as', 'df', 'er')
dfdre<-  a %>%
             group_by( as,df,er) %>%
             summarise_each_(funs(mean), one_of("wf", "sd", z1))
```